# How can I register concrete class based on last interface in structuremap

Tags: c#, structuremap

I have following interfaces and

```
public interface IHandleAService : IHandleDomainService
public interface IHandleBService : IHandleDomainService

public class AService : IHandleAService
public class BService : IHandleBService
```

How can I scan and register all these concrete classes based on 
IHandleDomainService interface in StructureMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(c => c.Scan(scan =>
{
    scan.TheCallingAssembly();
    scan.AddAllTypesOf<IHandleDomainService>();
}));
```